# Access textbox values on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page which accepts parameters and fills them in to the corresponding input fields.
With these parameters, a jquery function is called to load some content.
Now, in the jquery documentation I see "Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded."

It seems inside the document ready, my passed get value is already known.
But if the page contents are loaded afterwards, isn't it possible the value in the textfield will not be filled in when calling my 'loadContent' function ? Or is it already known by loading the DOM?
So my script below works fine, but why and will it always be the case?

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['test'])){
    echo '<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="' . $_GET['test'] . '">';
}else{
    echo '<input type="text" id="test" name="test">';
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("#test").val());
   loadContent($("#test").val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since your JS is below your `<input>` element (and in a `.ready()` callback), it'll load fine every time.

Comment: As it is inside a `ready` callback, even if its above the `<input>` it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your script AFTER you have already output the relevant HTML parts. I don't think you even need the .ready() function, just run the script after that point.
But a better way would be

```
<script>
$(window).load( function(){
    ...
});
</script>
```

within the head tags.

Comment: Did you mean `$(window).load(...)` ?